# AutoHotKey - switch statement with a series of InStr functions

Tags: script, autohotkey

I have created an AutoHotKey script with a bunch of `if` functions that rely on InStr, similarly as in the example below, and **it already does what I want**. Is it possible, though, to convert it to a `Switch` statement to simplify it and avoid repeating `if InStr...` several times?

The value of `fullPath` remains the same during the execution of the script.

```
fullPath = "%1%" 
;input examples: "c:\example\lalala lynx lalala.txt" and  "c:\another folder\test\kiwi testtest.txt"

if InStr(fullPath, "kiwi")
{
    Goto, FRUIT
}

if InStr(fullPath, "Estonia")
{
   Goto, COUNTRY
}

if InStr(fullPath, "lynx")
{
   Goto, ANIMAL
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an [associative array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays):

```
assocArray := { "kiwi" : "FRUIT" , "Estonia" : "COUNTRY" , "lynx" : "ANIMAL" }
for key, val in assocArray
{
    if InStr(fullPath, key)
        Goto, %val%
}
```

Comment: That's not I'm meant. I'm checking the same static variable (`fullPath`) with different strings, and my code already does what I want. I'm just wondering if I can convert it to a switch statement to avoid repeating the same function several times.

Comment: Try the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. However, note that AHK sorts these arrays alphabetically/in an ascending order, so even if you specify `kiwi` first, it starts the `for` loop with `Estonia` instead.